# Cast function pointer

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-2012, casting, reinterpret-cast

I've got quit a huge project to fix, there is a bug I can't resolve by myself:

```
class CEntity
{
public:
    CStudioHdr *        GetModelPtr();
public:
    CStudioHdr *        InternalGetModelPtr();
    static CStudioHdr * (ThisClass::* GetModelPtr_Actual) ();
}
```

Here is the function to cast to:

```
class GenericClass {};
typedef void (GenericClass::*VoidFunc)();

inline void *GetCodeAddr(VoidFunc mfp)
{
    return *(void **)&mfp;
}
```

The line, which doesn't let me to complie the project:

```
void *callback = (void *)GetCodeAddr(reinterpret_cast<VoidFunc>(&CEntity::InternalGetModelPtr));
```

I get this error:

```
error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'CStudioHdr *(__thiscall CEntity::* )(void)' to 'VoidFunc'
```

I gues it's something wrong with msvc compilers:

- Visual Studio 2012 (v110)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov2012)

The remarcable moment is that there is another class:

```
class CAnimating : public CEntity
{
```

And if I move this function into this class, there are no errors. 
I'm not sure if it's the best way to get a void pointer, is it correct for linux as well?

Comment: Well, just like an error says a pointer to `InternalGetModelPtr` is not compatible with `VoidFunc` and no amount of fancy casting can fix this.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the compiler. There's something seriously wrong with the shown code. No self-respecting C++ developer should be writing such terrible, awful type-unsafe spaghetti code. Perhaps, having dug into this, the compiler might get it wrong, but I wouldn't blame the compiler. The whole thing needs to be scrapped, fundamentally redesigned, and rewritten from scratch as type-safe, perhaps template-based or type-erased, proper C++ code.

Comment: I don't understend how it works, but it's part of SourceSDK